# Can I use this MUI outlined text field helper text without a text field?

Tags: material-ui

I want to use this [MUI outline-with-interpolated-label style](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/):

[image: MUI outline text field with helper text]

... but with a custom component inside, not a text field. Is that possible?